# Why insert statement generates 2 rows?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I dont know why, but when I do an insert statement in my project, its generate 2 indentical rows instead of makeing just one.

why is that ?

this is my code :

```
if (ListBox.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            string username = Session["Session"].ToString();

            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Daniel;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string knowWhichOne = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username='" + UserOrGuest.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(knowWhichOne, con);
            int userID = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();

            knowWhichOne = "SELECT ClassID FROM Users WHERE Username='" + UserOrGuest.Text + "'";

            comm = new SqlCommand(knowWhichOne, con);
            int classID = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();

            knowWhichOne = "SELECT SchoolID FROM Users WHERE Username='"+UserOrGuest.Text + "'";

            comm = new SqlCommand(knowWhichOne, con);
            int schoolID = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();

            if (RadioWords.Checked == true)
            {
                 game = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                 game = 2;
            }
            string arr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                arr += ListBox.Items[i] +",";
            }

            string sqlqueryString = "INSERT INTO HistoryOfGames (GameID, UserID, LengthOfArray, NumberOfErrors, ClassID, SchoolID,Arrayarray) VALUES (@GameID, @UserID, @LengthOfArray, @NumberOfErrors, @ClassID, @SchoolID, @Arrayarray);" + "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

            SqlCommand commandquery = new SqlCommand(sqlqueryString, con);

            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("GameID", game);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", userID);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("LengthOfArray", HowMany.Text);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("NumberOfErrors", 0);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("ClassID", classID);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("SchoolID", schoolID);
            commandquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("Arrayarray", arr);

            commandquery.ExecuteNonQuery();





            int IdOfRecentHistoryGame = (int)(decimal)commandquery.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

            Response.Redirect("NowPlay.aspx?ID="+ IdOfRecentHistoryGame);

        }
```

Comment: Can't you get "Select ID, ClassID, SchoolID From Users..." with one query and trip to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running it twice, ExecuteNonQuery() and ExecuteScalar(). Get rid of the ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 2):

you do

```
   commandquery.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

then right after

```
   int IdOfRecentHistoryGame = (int)(decimal)commandquery.ExecuteScalar();
```

you do execute it twice

and ***don't forget to check for sql injection in your code...***

Answer (score 1):

I'd check two things:

- see how many times this statement is executed (try setting a breakpoint to verify that the code is only run once)
- see if there are any triggers in the database that might cause an extra record to be inserted

Comment: When I debug it, its running only once.   what kind of triggers might cause this?

Comment: However, Stu discovered the real cause. No need to check anything else

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem,I handled it this way.not professional but it works:

`Dim x As Boolean = True`

`If x = True Then`

`here goes your code to insert to database.`

`End If`

`x = False`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is wrong in so many ways... 1) unless you are multithreaded, X is still going to be true 2) If x = true? Really? How about If X? and 3) how does this address the actual issue?